# Prove that $l = k/\gcd(m,k)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, congruences

Suppose $ml = kt$ where $t$ is an integer and $m<k.$

$\implies k~|~ml$  $~~~~~$and $~~~~~$ $1 \leq \gcd(m,k) \leq m$

$\implies \dfrac{k}{\gcd(m,k)}~\Big|~\left(\dfrac{m}{\gcd(m,k)}\right)l$

What am I missing?

Comment: $l | 2l$ as well, so $m/(m,k) = 2$ is a possibility.  $l | x$ does not mean $x = l$; the last statement does not follow.

Comment: Downvoter: while the attempted proof may fail, that's precisely what the OP was hoping to learn. If all users asking questions showed effort like that shown here, we'd all be a lot happier.